# Coldfusion - Output checkboxes

Tags: database, web, coldfusion, filemaker

**Situation**

I'm using ColdFusion to build out a new web application and converting over an old Filemaker database.

**Problem**

I have a bunch of checkboxes, the values are already set, but I am trying to figure out how to output the checkboxes with their values to a web page without allowing the user to modify the value. I just need the output to display.

Is there a way to accomplish this using ColdFusion?

Comment: You should post some code for us to look at so that we are sure of what question you are asking.

Comment: Do you need to pass over the checkbox status, or just show something to the user?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like simple HTML. Disabling the checkbox will disable the user from changing checking or unchecking.

```
<cfif VARIABLES.IsChecked eq true>
    <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked>
<cfelse>
    <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
</cfif>
```

Comment: It will also prevent the values from posting, in the unlikely event that it's important.

Comment: you can also do this in one line as `<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"<cfif IsChecked> checked="checked"</cfif>>`

Comment: I didn't mean to hit the checkbox!!! I do think this is pointing me in the correct direction, I just need it to show if the box was checked or unchecked, and don't want it to be edited unless they hit the "edit" button for the page. Just want the value for the checkbox to display for viewing purposes when people are searching through the records. I'll let you know if this works out for me.